# How to make "Announce on LinkedIn" on by default?

Tags: 7, social-network

I am using [Linkedin](http://drupal.org/project/linkedin) module.

I want "Announce on LinkedIn" turned on by default. I am using [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module for RSS. It automatically created Feed and Feed Item Content types. RSS content is automatically saved as new node. But that node is not posted in Linkedin. I have to edit the content and manually check "Announce on LinkedIn" to have it posted:

[image: Refer this Image]

I want it posted automatically. How can I achieve that? Please anyone help to me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the LinkedIn post functionality is tied to the node form; the form is altered to add the [form component & submission hook](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/linkedin/tree/linkedin.module#n177). However, Feeds isn't using this form so it will never get a chance to process the submission handler.

If you look at the [submission handler](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/linkedin/tree/linkedin.pages.inc#n241) you can pull out the relevant function, [`linkedin_put_profile_field()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/linkedin/tree/linkedin.inc#n127),  to make this happen. Combine this with [hook_feeds_after_import()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!feeds!feeds.api.php/function/hook_feeds_after_import/7), and you can come up with an implementation that will trigger a LinkedIn post upon a feed import:

```
function MYMODULE_feeds_after_import(FeedsSource $source) {
  if(function_exists('linkedin_put_profile_field') && isset($source->feed_nid) && $node = node_load($source->feed_nid) {
    $status = variable_get('linkedin_default_format_'. $node->type, '');
    linkedin_put_profile_field($node->uid, 'current-status', $status);
  }
}
```

Note: there will probably need to be more checks & altercations here based on your needs (e.g. setting the right UID to post as, throttling posting so your feed importing doesn't get marked as spam on LinkedIn).